# SpreadsheetGear DataLabel Font Formatting

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I am trying to create a single bold DataLabel on a chart using SpreadsheetGear.  I can set the number to be Green using the code below:

```
DataLabels(0).NumberFormat = "[Green]###,###,##0"
```

But when I attempt to set a property of the Font nothing appears to happen.  I have tried the below with no success.

```
DataLabels(0).Font.Bold = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have should work. If you have other code that is manipulating the series that the data labels belong to, try putting the line

```
DataLabels(0).Font.Bold = True
```

after any such code.

Comment: Thanks, I moved that code to the end of my chart generation and it does indeed work as expected.